# Would install LAMP conflict with python?

Tags: apache2, python, php, mysql, lamp

I am currently using ubuntu 14.04.
I have PyCharm installed and using django-oscar with mysql.
I am wondering what I would install in order to get php working?

I am used to windows installing wamp to get localhost working for php but I have no single clue what's the best way to do it in Ubuntu and I don't want to duplicate any installs.

I have searched and found commands to install lamp which would get apache, php and mysql.  Would this actually conflict anything with django-oscar? Would there be a duplicate installation with mysql?

Sorry if this didn't make sense in a way.

Thanks in advance

Comment: there's no connection whatsoever between php and python, no conflict whatsoever, just install this

https://www.apachefriends.org the linux version

Answer (score 1):

Python is not related to any of the `lamp` packages. So no, they shouldn't conflict with each other.

P.S. If you do not need the full LAMP stack, you don't have to install all of its packages. For example, if you need to install just PHP Apache, you can do that by running

```
sudo apt-get install php5
```

If you need both Apache and PHP, then you would run

```
sudo apt-get install php5 apache2
```

Comment: I am actually trying to install laravel with homestead